# C - Binary Search Tree, delete node

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I have a question about my Code. "delete_single_node" does not work as it should. My procedure (to delete a node) is to find the node in the "head" tree, save the child nodes temporary, delete the node and all child nodes (in "head" tree) and merge the "head" tree with the temporary saved child nodes to a new correct binary tree.
I would like to stay with this procedure but I can't find my mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct tnode {
    int content; 
    struct tnode *left; 
    struct tnode *right; 
};

struct tnode* head;

void *malloc(size_t size);
struct tnode *talloc(void)
{
    return(struct tnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}




/* delete a node with all child nodes*/
int deletenode(struct tnode *p)
{
    if (p == NULL) return 0;
    else
    {
        deletenode(p->left);
        deletenode(p->right);
        p->left = NULL;
        p->right = NULL;
        free(p);
        return 0;
    }
}


/* insert new node*/
struct tnode *addelement(struct tnode *p, int i) {
    int cond;
    if (p == NULL) {
        p = talloc(); 
        p->content = i;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (p->content == i) {
        return p;
    }
    else if (i < p->content)
        p->left = addelement(p->left, i);
    else 
        p->right = addelement(p->right, i);
    return p;
}

/*merges two binary trees into one*/
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *top, struct tnode *p) {
    if (p == NULL)
        return top;
    else
        return addtree(addtree(addelement(top, p->content), p->right), p->left);
}
/*prints out tree*/
void showtree(struct tnode* nd)
{
    if (nd == NULL)
        return;
    printf("ZZ %d", nd->content);
    if (nd->left != NULL)
    {
        printf("left:%d", nd->left->content);
    }
    if (nd->right != NULL)
    {
        printf("right:%d\n", nd->right->content);
    }
    printf("\n");
    showtree(nd->left);
    showtree(nd->right);
}
/*removes connection to a node*/
void removeconnection(struct tnode *head, struct tnode *p) {
    if (p->content > head->content) {
        if (head->right == p)
        {
            head->right = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            removeconnection(head->right, p);
        }       
    }
    if (p->content < head->content) {
        if (head->left == p)
        {
            head->left = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            removeconnection(head->left, p);
        }
    }
}


/*delete single node*/
struct tnode *delete_single_node(struct tnode *p, int content) {
    struct tnode* temp2 = NULL;
    struct tnode temp1;
    struct tnode* temp4 = NULL;
    struct tnode temp3;

    if (p == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (content > p->content)
    {
        p->right = delete_single_node(p->right, content);
    }
    else if (content < p->content)
    {
        p->left = delete_single_node(p->left, content);
    }
    else if (content == p->content)
    {
        if (p->left == NULL && p->right != NULL)
        {

            temp1.content = p->right->content;
            temp1.right = p->right->right;
            temp1.left = p->right->left;
            temp2 = &temp1;

            removeconnection(head, p);
            deletenode(p); 
            head = addtree(head, temp2);
            showtree(head);
        }
        else if (p->right == NULL && p->left != NULL)
        {
            temp1.content = p->left->content;
            temp1.right = p->left->right;
            temp1.left = p->left->left;
            temp2 = &temp1;

            removeconnection(head, p);
            deletenode(p);
            head = addtree(head, temp2);        
            showtree(head);
        }
        else if (p->right == NULL && p->left == NULL)
        {
            removeconnection(head, p);
            deletenode(p);
            showtree(head);
        }
        else
        {
            temp1.content = p->left->content;
            temp1.right = p->left->right;
            temp1.left = p->left->left;
            temp2 = &temp1;

            temp3.content = p->right->content;
            temp3.right = p->right->right;
            temp3.left = p->right->left;
            temp4 = &temp3;

            removeconnection(head, p);
            deletenode(p);
            head = addtree(head, temp2);
            head = addtree(head, temp4);
            showtree(head);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct tnode* start = NULL;
    int temp_int;
    start = addelement(start, 5);
    start = addelement(start, 6);
    start = addelement(start, 2);
    start = addelement(start, 9);
    start = addelement(start, 3);
    start = addelement(start, 2);
    start = addelement(start, 1);
    start = addelement(start, 7);
    start = addelement(start, 8);

    showtree(start);

    printf("Which node to delete?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &temp_int);
    head = start;
    delete_single_node(start, temp_int);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Time to go and read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: I also recommend adding more comments in the code about some of the less obvious parts. Like in the `addtree` function, why are you calling itself recursively *twice*? Things like that, and other non-obvious parts needs comments. Not only for us to understand now, but for yourself in the future as well.

Comment: I know how to debug, but I am new to C. To specify the problem, when I safe the node values in temp1, why the "deletenode" method removes also nodes from temp1? Isn't it saved on a different place now and away from the "p" node and child nodes?

Comment: The problem is probably that you save *pointers* instead of actually duplicating the sub-tree. I'm also a little worried about the use of `temp2` (and `temp4`) as a pointer to local variables (that will go out of scope once the function returns).

Comment: Ok, thank you, how I actually duplicate the sub-tree? I mean temp1 isn't a pointer or am I wrong?

Comment: No but e.g. `temp1.right` and `temp1.left` are pointers to sub-trees. If `deletenode(p)` deletes those sub-trees as well then those pointers will no longer be valid. Finding out these things is what you use a debugger for. You will see that e.g. `temp1.right` points to some node, and later you will see that `deletenode` will delete that node.

Comment: So I have the only possibility to make temp1.right and temp1.left not pointers?

Comment: no, you can make a deep copy -- you'd need a function to copy a subtree given a root node.  The function would follow the pointers.  But all this copying looks inefficient.  You have pointers; use them.  Instead of copying everything back and forth, make a temp pointer point to the node you want to delete.  Then merge what you need to merge by having the above pointers point to the nodes that the node to be deleted pointed to.  Then delete the node through the temp pointer.

Comment: `delete_single_node()` does not return any value (only NULL), but it should return `tnode`.

Comment: @No110 can you give the case where it fails?

Comment: ok i got the error, when you copy node to temp1 and temp3, you are only copying the current node while all other(child) nodes are the original ones. So, when you use the delete function, these nodes are also deleted which gives the error. So, in delete function deleting only the current node ie using `free(p)` only and not making recursive calls helps in soving your problem. @vadim_hr as we are dealing with pointers and making changes in them, these changes are retained, so returning tnode doesnt make a diff

Comment: @monster  probably you should not use returning value in this piece of code `p->right = delete_single_node(p->right, content);`

Comment: @vadim_hr k right my bad you are right

Comment: I have a ready Version of it, it's not beautiful but it works. If someone want's it I can post it?